# An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected Near LEFT JOIN USER

Tags: sql, sql-server

```sql
SELECT A.Id as ID, 
    A.Industry__c as Industry
FROM Opportunity AS A
LEFT JOIN ACCOUNT AS B
     ON A.AccountId = B.Id  
LEFT JOIN User AS C --Error here; there is a table called USER still getting an error
     ON A.OWNERID = C.USERROLEID
Where CloseDate BETWEEN '2021/01/01' and '2021/03/31'
      AND StageName IN ('WON AND CLOSED', 'H. WON AND CLOSED')
```

Is giving error:

> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected Near LEFT JOIN USER

Comment: Do you really use MySQL? Not MS SQL aka SQL Server?

Comment: You really need to ask a question and clarify what you have found when you researched this error and why it doesn't solve you issue. Just code + error does not make a question.

Comment: When several tables are involved, it's good programming practice to qualify all columns. You might know it, but we don't know which table for example CloseDate belongs to.

Comment: [Bad Habits to Kick : Using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`USER` is a reserved word in SQL Server.

Try putting it in square brackets.

```
SELECT A.Id as ID, 
    A.Industry__c as Industry
FROM Opportunity AS A
LEFT JOIN ACCOUNT AS B
     ON A.AccountId = B.Id  
LEFT JOIN [User] AS C
     ON A.OWNERID = C.USERROLEID
Where CloseDate BETWEEN '2021/01/01' and '2021/03/31'
      AND StageName IN ('WON AND CLOSED', 'H. WON AND CLOSED')
```

Comment: Good to know @Vishal. Feel free to accept the answer :)

Comment: I believe I've accepted the answer too, new to stackoverflow. :)